# Setting Paypal Checkout Price

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Recently I've wanted to do an online shop via PayPal and have done single products really well,
However recently I wanted to do a cart system and one problem I now have is setting a PayPal checkout price to one of the php total var. I know about IPN's but I need to set the price before the redirect to the PayPal checkout.

Any help will be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't share any code for your checkout, here are the best options:

1) [Demo pattern of front-end that uses client-side code only](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

2) [Demo pattern of front-end that calls server-side endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), which would need to implement order creation and capture APIs.

In the case of #1 the amount is set in the client-side JS code, so your PHP code would need to output that code with the variable set in the appropriate place.

In the case of #2 the code will call an endpoint on your server, which would need to call the PayPal API to create a payment object with the amount set, and return that payment object's unique orderID to the checkout in the XHR response body so that it can proceed.